# How do i get an output from this code using excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get output from this code as excel or csv file. But as the output is in list i am not being able to. Is there a way to convert the list object to dataframe and get the value in excel or csv?

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('Training.xls') # get input from excel files
df2 = pd.read_excel('Newsss.xlsx') #comparing them
info = df2.shape
totalRow = info[0]

print(totalRow)

    for r in range (0,totalRow):
        lst = df2.iloc[r,:]
        x=df1.iloc[r,1]
        cnt = 0
        l = []

        for i in lst:
            if cnt==0:
                l.append(i)
                cnt=1
                continue
            elif (i-x)==0:
                l.append(1) # condition for my program to work on excel files
            elif abs(i-x) > 0.2:
                l.append(0)
            else:
                l.append(i)
        print(l)
```

At the moment this is the output i am getting when i print(l) but i need this value store in excel or csv as row wise,

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCACb.png)

Comment: At the moment you are getting a syntax error from bad indentation.

Comment: Please don't post images where formatted text will do

Comment: Import your array to another df, dataframes have methods to transpose and save to csv ...

Comment: @kickaha the issue i am having at the moment is the output is not taking the column names .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a matrix with all your lists `l`, than transform to a data frame so as to write it in a csv:

```
# Big matrix with all your lists
m = []

for r in range (0,totalRow):
    lst = df2.iloc[r,:]
    x=df1.iloc[r,1]
    cnt = 0
    l = []

    for i in lst:
        if cnt==0:
            l.append(i)
            cnt=1
            continue
        elif (i-x)==0:
            l.append(1) # condition for my program to work on excel files
        elif abs(i-x) > 0.2:
            l.append(0)
        else:
            l.append(i)

    # Append your new list to the matrix
    m.append(l)

# Create the data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(m)

# If you have the columns names you may create the df this way
# If the columns names are the same of df1:
columns_names = df1.columns
df = pd.DataFrame(m, columns = columns_names)

file_name = "your_file_name.csv"
df.to_csv(file_name, m)

# You can add a separator like ',', '\t', ';' ...
# df.to_csv(file_name, m, sep = ',')
```

If you have to transpose your matrix, you can do:

```
import numpy as np

# Create a matrix object
m = np.matrix(m)

# Transpose your matrix
m = m.T
```

Than you can store your data in a data frame as before.

Comment: Thank you so much , Can you tell me something when i compare them how do i keep the previous column name rather than index values there?

Comment: If your columns names are the same of `df1` or `df2` you can include them when you create `df`. I put a comment in my solution about this.

Comment: thanks it's working now :) Can you tell me how do i count the non zero values in a whole excel sheet column wise?  I mean ignore the value if it's zero and count the rest, which contains float values as well.

Also, as my first row contains names like Sf_1011 i want to ignore the first row of the excel file completely so it counts only the floats, not alphanumeric.